# Integration of simple functions: Am I right understanding it this way?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathscr{F}}$
I had the same question when learning the integral in Mesure theory (Like this one Standard vs. regular representations of simple functions., URL (version: 2022-12-06): [Standard vs. regular representations of simple functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4592878)) and searched for a better understanding in the forum. However, they are not that clear to me. I came up with an idea but not sure whether it is correct or not.

For the sake of simplicity, we confine to analyzing the integral of non-negative simple functions.

> **Definition:** Let $(\Omega, \scrF, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\phi:\Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a non-negative simple function iff it can be written as
> $$
> \phi(\omega)= \sum_{k=1}^m a_k\chi_{D_k}(\omega)
> $$
> where $a_k >=0, \chi_{D_k}$ denotes the characteristic function of $D_k$.

We can simply do a trick to make $D_k$ pairwise disjoint and $ \cup D_k=\Omega$ (Note: we do not say the set of $D_k$ forms a partition of $\Omega$ because it may contain the empty set)

For example, $c\chi(A)+d\chi(B)=(c+d)\chi_{A\cap B}+c\chi_{A\cap B^{c}}+d\chi_{A^{c}\cap B}+0\chi_{A^{c}\cap B^{c}}$

We call it a **standard representation** of the simple function $\phi$.

Now we can define the integral of a simple function based on the standard representation
$Int(\phi(\omega))= \sum_{k=1}^m a_k \mu(D_k)$
and many books have shown that it is well-defined (Not reliable on the standard representation).

However, like me, many have asked if it is not in the standard representation, Will $Int(\phi(\omega))= \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \mu(E_j)$ be true, where $E_j$ s may not be disjoint and their union may not be the whole set?

If the case of two is correct, then the case of arbitrary natural number is correct. Still using the above example, $c\chi(A)+d\chi(B)=(c+d)\chi_{A\cap B}+c\chi_{A\cap B^{c}}+d\chi_{A^{c}\cap B}+0\chi_{A^{c}\cap B^{c}}$

Will
$c\mu(A)+d\mu(B)=(c+d)\mu(A\cap B)+c\mu(A\cap B^{c})+d\mu(A^{c}\cap B)+0\mu(A^{c}\cap B^{c})$ be true?

The answer is Yes by the finite additivity of measure.